# What caused my answer to get deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I had 62 reputation earlier today and now it has decreased to 37. This has caused me to lose the privilege of commenting everywhere.

I have lost 25 reputation. This has happened because my answer had 1 upvote, was an accepted answer and has been deleted from my account's activity.

Can an explanation be provided for this deletion?

Comment: You'll have to link to the answer. If you go to your answers page in your profile, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the list that says something like "show recently deleted posts".

Comment: @TinyGiant unfortunately that link is "deleted recent posts". If the answer was any age it won't show up there.

Comment: I am pretty sure the quetion got deleted, was the question closed?

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa *waitaminute* why are all of the downvotes being piled on to this question?  Doesn't seem like they were aware of why the post was deleted nor is the OP aware of the preservation rule we have in place for some deleted posts.

Comment: I personally downvoted this because (a) it's not asking why an answer was deleted, it's asking *who* deleted the answer — which doesn't seem like it can possibly yield anything productive.  And (b) because it makes the claim "*this is not fair*", which is almost pleading for downvotes.

Comment: @COrNotToC And why you need to know the 3 users? simply consider that your post got deleted by the community due to some reasons. I would probably ask for *the reasons* not the users

Comment: It does mean 3 different users delete voted the question. A delete vote can only be casted once on a post.

Comment: Not really sure what the big deal is about asking "who", but the post has been edited, @billynoah.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - It's not a big deal, I was just offering up an explanation to Makoto since he asked. Thanks for the edit, looks better.

Comment: @billynoah, I just want to know who has deleted my post because I have not deleted it myself. ChrisF's answer below explains it took three votes for my post to be deleted.  I am not pleading for downvotes. Who would do that anyway? ChrisF has already fully answered my question so nothing more needs to be discussed.

Comment: @Temani Afif, I have already received an excellent answer from ChrisF that I am satisfied with. Nothing more needs to be discussed.

Comment: Hey there. The crowd on meta like to discuss things. We are free to do so, even after you've learned more about question deletion :)

Comment: @COrNotToC - "pleading for downvotes" is a figure of speech. It may not make sense if you are not a native English speaker but it's just a way of saying that a statement like that, in this environment is *very likely* to attract downvotes. Arming yourself with that knowledge might help you garner a more positive response on future meta posts.  Don't feel bad, users with hundreds of thousands of rep still occasionally get downvoted in to the depths of /dev/null here.

Comment: I am glad to have helped the person that had asked the question, regardless of whether or not they deserved my help. That is what counts at the end of the day. I am not worried about the reputation I have lost anymore. It is time to move on. :)

Comment: @billynoah, I understand what you are saying completely. I am a native English speaker. I am not bothered about the reputation I have lost anymore. At least I have learned something new from this experience. :)

Comment: @COrNotToC Well this site isn't a help desk.  It's not a place for individual tutoring.  It's a place to generate a repository of knowledge for the programming community as a whole.  Thus, when you provide content that doesn't aid in that endeavor, it may be deleted.

Comment: @Servy, my answer answered the question perfectly. That is why the OP had chosen it as the accepted answer. Everything that occurred after that was beyond my control. I wonder whether other members agree with your stance.

Comment: @COrNotToC Apparently *the question* was so bad that an answer to it wasn't a useful contribution to the programming community, or so the readers of the question felt. That the author of the question accepted the answer doesn't mean that it was either a good answer to the question (many people accept answers that are not good answers) or a useful addition to the programming community as a whole.

Comment: @COrNotToC Yes, other members do agree with that stance. The upvotes on the comment are an indication of that. The question deletion as well. Unless you mean the "It's not a place for individual tutoring."? That's pretty much widely accepted. The medium itself, Q&A, is really not tailored for individual help, and really supports the idea that a question should not only be relevant to its asker, but to the community as well.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier, is valuable information such as this readily accessible? Should it be if it is not?

Comment: @COrNotToC It is! You can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), for instance, and then continue with the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages. A few key citations: "`With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.`" and "`This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.`". Individual tutoring does not fit in a no chit-chat place.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier Unfortunately, I have only earned the "Informed" badge, which is earned by reading the entire tour page, today after another user informed me of it. I was not aware of it before this happened, although I believe I should have been. Do these citations apply to Meta Stack Overflow as well?

Comment: @COrNotToC Generally, yes, but we are a bit more relaxed about it. Look around, read highly scored posts and comments, you should get a feel of how it differs from the site.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your answer was deleted because the question was deleted.

The question was closed in June of 2018 at which point it became eligible for deletion.

With the post score being relatively low it took three votes for it to be deleted. It appears that all three votes came today, but I can't see what would have prompted them.

Don't worry about the loss of reputation, just find another question or two to answer and you'll soon regain it.

Comment: How can I view these decisions?,

Comment: @COrNotToC There's not really anything to view. There are just three delete votes. Who voted is recorded, but we have no way of knowing *why* they voted. I don't think anything would be gained by publicising their names.

Comment: I do not wish to publicise anyone's names. I am just a bit surprised because I had no idea about this decision. This decision has caused me to lose a privilege.

Comment: @COrNotToC If I share a link I *will* publicise their names. If I share a redacted screenshot it doesn't really help you as all that does is confirm that the question is deleted.

Comment: @COrNotToC The statement that the question was deleted is enough.   Unless you for some reason think Chris is lying to you (or is somehow mistaken about something so simple).  Do you think so?  If so, why?

Comment: @ChrisF, thank you for providing an explanation. Nothing more is required.

Comment: @Servy, I am not here to accuse anybody of anything. I just wanted information about the deletion of my answer and ChrisF has very generously provided that information.

Comment: @ChrisF: But if you share the link, some helpful 10K users may vote to undelete the question, and restore OP's reputation, if the question isn't too terrible...

Comment: @user000001 the question is closed, hence it's been deemed off topic. It also remained closed for 6 months before being deleted. There seems little point in undeleting it as it's not going to get reopened and will probably get deleted again.

Comment: *"This decision has caused me to lose a privilege."* - mmm, that's not the whole truth. You answered a question which was deemed off-topic. The fact that you did not identify the off-topicness of the question yourself caused your effort to write it to be for nothing. The fact that you lost reputation and a privilege is all just a side effect. So hopefully the learning moment is: be very aware that there are questions you shouldn't answer, or these things happen. The site help has some guidelines which can help to identify such questions.

Answer (score 3):

## Specific case

Your answer was deleted because the question was deleted.

The question where you had your answer was closed by 5 people for being off-topic, and this is what you were able to read on the question itself for more than 6 months:

> "Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about)." – theB, IInspectable, Ryan Bemrose, Pang, Undo

It was deleted in January 2019 by **3 other** people, at their own discretion. And reviewing the deleted question (privilege of 10,000+ reputation users), I see no reason to undelete it.

## General case

You may read about why questions are deleted in the help center:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions.

> ### Why and how are some questions deleted?
>
> Questions that are [extremely off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/on-topic), or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.

The help center also links to this FAQ: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> ### What are the criteria for deletion?
>
> For questions, a post that [no longer adds *anything* to the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054) should be deleted. Basically, this includes most closed questions that cannot be improved and reopened.